# How to get my current user logon in MS Access forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have initial form logon to Validate user details to access my MS Access database.

Now I have a requirement in another form, If I choose same logon user from a combo box then command button should be enabled in the form so how I validate my initial logon user who logged in with another form Textbox in my access db.

So I researched about this but could not get the useful scenario - Can some please help me how I can acheive this details ..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user completes her login, hide rather than close the login form.  With the form hidden, code in your other form can still read values from the login form.

To hide a form named frmLogin:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogin",acNormal,,,,acHidden
```

or

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogin",acNormal,WindowMode:=acHidden
```

If the hidden frmLogin includes a text box named txtUserName, you can inspect its value like this:

```
Debug.Print Forms!frmLogin!txtUserName
```

I based this answer on the assumption you created your own security framework in your Access database application.  But that point is unclear.  If you're using Access ULS (user level security), which requires the older MDB format database, the CurrentUser() function which Matt mentioned will give you the user's Access security name.  However, if that is the approach you're using, I don't understand why you would need a separate login form.

So your question is unclear.  If none of the answers is satisfactory, please edit your question to include an explanation of the security/login strategy you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the API approach @Remou suggests works, I have moved to this technique

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String
    Dim wshNet As Object
    Set wshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    GetUserName = wshNet.UserName
    Set wshNet = Nothing
End Function
```

I believe it to be more robust than calling an API

Answer (score 0):

Record the logged on user in a public variable once validated and then you can test this against the "CurrentUser()" command to see if they match on next form.

NOTE: Only use this method if each user has their own copy of the front-end (do not use if everyone is sharing the same front-end, although with good practice they shouldn't be)

Comment: I am not sure that current user is going to be helpful if Access security is not used ("Admin" will be returned) and Environ("username") is poor security. API such as Dev Ashish's (http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm) is often recommended. I am not sure what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Remou I wasn't too sure whether the OP is using the 'Windows' username as their security of whether they are using some other method, otherwise yes, the API call is good and I also like Chris' answer.